# How to bulk remove components from an unlocked package?

Tags: managed-package, tooling-api, unlocked-package

As part of this effort [Preserving org data when converting orgs from an unlocked package to a managed package version of the same code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/387978/preserving-org-data-when-converting-orgs-from-an-unlocked-package-to-a-managed-p) I'm looking for a way to remove hundreds of items from an unlocked package.

The Package Details UI is OK when deleting a few items, but because it's super-slow it's not viable for deleting lots. (There is a confirmation token involved so does not look easy to hack either.) So approaches such as [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331217/remove-component-from-unlocked-package-programmatically) that require manual removes are impractical. Imagine this page hundreds of lines long:

[image: Package Detail]

I got pretty excited when I found [Package2Member](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_package2member.htm) in the tooling API and you can query the same information that the UI shows in the Developer Console:

```
select Id, SubscriberPackage.Name, SubjectId, SubjectManageableState
from Package2Member
```

but any attempt to delete results in:

> insufficient access rights on object id

which is consistent with the documentation that says:

> **Supported REST HTTP Methods**
>
> Query, GET

but if there was a viable Tooling API approach I would go for it. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed that the "package with no elements" approach does not work for custom objects and custom fields whichever of `DeprecateOnly`, `Mixed` or `Delete` are used in the install; there is mention of:

> except for custom objects and custom fields

So I have a 70 line Node/Selenium script that clicks all the "Remove" links. Each click takes about 10 seconds on average, but by running many instances, the elapsed time for me is less than an hour overall. Way less nice than an API that does this work on a few seconds, but AFAIK the only option at the moment.

**PS**

I created a support case and the outcome of that was that the solution is to uninstall the unlocked package and then install the managed package (requiring the data to be re-instated afterwards).

Here is the Node/Selenium script per the comment. I'm posting this on a no questions answered, no support, no liability, use at your own risk basis. Ensure the user you are running this under has "Classic" selected. Running many instances at once speeds things up.

```
"use strict";

const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')

// Run Chrome without a window appearing on the screen
const options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments('--headless');

const by = webdriver.By;
const until = webdriver.until;

async function selenium(username, password, loginUrl, viewComponentsUrl) {

    const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();

    await driver.get(loginUrl);
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.name('username')));
    await driver.findElement(by.name('username')).sendKeys(username);
    await driver.findElement(by.name('pw')).sendKeys(password);
    const b = await driver.findElement(by.css('input.button'));
    b.click();

    await driver.sleep(5 * 1000);
    console.log('...logged in');

    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.css('div.menuButtonButton')));

    await driver.get(viewComponentsUrl);
    console.log('...components page opened');

    let lastCount = -1;
    while (true) {
        const t1 = Date.now();

        // Wait for page to appear
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.css('a.actionLink')), 2 * 60 * 1000);

        // See how many links
        const removes = await driver.findElements(by.css('a.actionLink'));
        const count = removes.length;
        if (count === 0) {
            console.log('...all done!');
            return;
        }
        if (lastCount === -1) lastCount = count;

        // Click a random one to work better when multiple instances running
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
        await removes[index].click();
        await driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

        // Output progress
        const t2 = Date.now();
        const seconds = Math.floor((t2 - t1) / 1000);
        const secondsPerLink = ((t2 - t1) / (1000 * (lastCount - count))).toFixed(3);
        console.log(`...link index ${index} removed in ${seconds} seconds; overall rate is ${secondsPerLink} seconds per link; ${count - 1} links remaining`);

        lastCount = count;
    }
}

selenium(
    'test-xxx',
    'xxx',
    'https://test.salesforce.com/',
    'https://xxx-xxx-xxx-dev-ed.scratch.my.salesforce.com/0A37i000000LFOA?pkgComp=show'
);
```

**PPS**

I've hit these 3 further problems (so far) after having removed the components from the unlocked package:

- LWC references to namespaced Apex fail with the message "Apex action method 'Abc.def' with public access modifier must be in the same package with caller 'markup://ns:lwcName" even though in both the org and the package the namespace is in place; an (ugly) work around to that is to create a package version with the Apex references removed using a regex to install first then a version with that put back to install second
- This https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwfUAAS/unlocked-package-upgrade-fails-if-lookup-field-with-filter-is-removed-from-the-subscriber-org; handled by writing a pre-API 30 version script on top of [financialforcedev
  /
  apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to delete the `NamedFilter` metadata.
- Hit a similar problem with custom labels. As they are depended on, had to rename them all.

Comment: I also have to delete all the metadata one by one. and it's a long painful process. Can you share the script? @keith

Comment: Hi @snl, Sure will post it tomorrow. Do understand this will be on a no questions answered, no support, no liability, use at your own risk basis.

Comment: I think object and fields are not only metadata which are not removed. Also LiveChatButton, Skill, Flow, Digital Experience Bundle, Layout, Button, Quick Action and many more. At least most of them can be removed manually from unlocked package except for the LiveChatButton and Skill.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new package version that contains no elements (or perhaps some dummy element), and use the upgrade type "DeprecateOnly" when upgrading. All of your metadata will be in a Deprecated status, ready to be added to the new package.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, Yep I've tried that. But the components still also have to be removed from the unlocked package to avoid errors like this one "Cannot add component of type:Layout named:Custom__c-Custom Layout subjectId:00h8F000001xQjr to another package because it is an installed component." The error occurs across all metadata types, hence the idea of a bulk "Remove".

Comment: @KeithC Weird. I would think after deprecation, it would have been removed from the package. That's been my experience so far, although it's been a little bit since I've done anything with unlocked packages. Let me try it out on a package I have lying around.

Comment: Very much appreciated @sfdcfox - thanks. This is a 2GP unlocked package that I'm trying to convert to a managed package that is live with customers so preserving custom record and custom field data is a priority.

Comment: @KeithC I don't think what you're trying to do is possible? Have you engineered this solution with Dev Support or Partner Support to make sure that this is a viable strategy? I'm not convinced you can move metadata between a 2UP and 2GP, even if they're in the same namespace, and even if you could, I think a subscriber would have to uninstall the 2UP before installing the 2GP, or... subscribers will have to each manually remove those hundreds of references over and over again. If you want to move this over to the Salesforce Ohana Slack, you can find me on there.

Comment: Thanks - the approach was established before I joined the company... I've messaged you on LinkedIn as Salesforce Ohana Slack registration says "you’ll need to ask the person who originally invited you for a new link". But agree, not likely to be possible; I've created a SF case but will be days before that gets to anyone with sufficient knowledge to respond.